# FileProvider Class Unresolved

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fileprovider

I am trying to do [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

I have followed all the steps but I am unable to build due to an error stating

> Unresolved Class FileProvider

I have the support repository installed. My current grade is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

How do I get Android Studio to recognize the `FileProvider` class?

Here is what is inside the Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

    </application>
```

Comment: You specify `minSdkVersion 19`, while [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) was introduced in sdk `22`.

Comment: I've changed the minimum to 22, but still have the same error.

Comment: I set minSdkVersion to 27 and I still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your module's gradle file's `dependencies`.

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'`