# Unresolved class 'FileProvider'

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to take a picture on an android device and following [this tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en).

The below code gives me an error on `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`. Android studio says **Unresolved class 'FileProvider'**.

I have the following AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.camera">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".LandingPageActivity" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I have added `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` to my `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camera"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    ...others
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143654/fileprovider-class-unresolved) with no luck.

Comment: Since you are using androidx dependency you shouldn't use anything below android x such as support-v4:28. Use this : implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' instead.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're using AndroidX dependencies (such as your `androidx.appcompat` dependency), so you need to use the [AndroidX FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.html), which has a package name of `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

</provider>
```